# Red5 - Stream a list of videos in sequence by server

Tags: java, red5

I need to make a dynamic list of videos with Red5. The videos should be played in sequence by the ser ver, regardless of wheter the user has loggeed on or not.

It's like a normal TV, with sequential programming. When several users try to connect simultaneously, they will see the same video running at the time.

However, I have no idea where to start. How to make this list and play it by Red5? To which port do the users need to connect?

Roughly, it is like a AutoDJ shoutcast, where the radio runs on a port and autoDJ on another, playing the files, and users connect to the port of the main radio.

I will appreciate any source or link on this!

Comment: Why -1? Do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://red5.electroteque.org/dev/demos/playlistTest.zip` is a demo project to create a red5 server app playlist. On the flash client side you will need to create a `NetConnection` and `NetStream` to connect and play the videos, the default `rtmp` port is 1935 but it also can be configure to run under the 80 or 8080 ports through the `rtmpt` protocol. 
Anyway study this demo project, I think this is a start to get you working into this project and later post more specific question about the issues you face.

Comment: Hi fmodos, thank you!  I will see this project.

Comment: fmodos, this project run a playlist without user connect?? I need a playlist running with no users. Like a shoutcast autodj.

Comment: A better explain is: I need a server bot streaming local server files, like a live streaming...

Comment: it starts stream when the start function of the ServerPlaylist class is invoked, so you can invoke it in the startup of your server.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore, could you fix?